# not able to set property of interface type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecma

I am beginner in typescript programming not able to set property interface type so please guide me about that.

```
interface addition { 
    num1: number;
    num2: number;
    add(num1:number, num2:number): number;
}

class Calculator implements addition{
    num1: number;
    num2: number;
    adds: addition;   //

    add(num1: number, num2: number): number { 
        return num1 + num2;
    }    

    sub(num1: number, num2: number): number { 
        let sk: addition = new Calculator()
        console.log(sk.add(2, 3)); 
        this.adds.num1=12;   // showing error here Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'num1' of undefined
        console.log(this.adds.num1)
        return num1-num2
    }
}

let cal = new Calculator();
console.log(cal.sub(2, 3));
```

Comment: Try turning on `--strict` for better error catching in TypeScript.  Specifically you want [`--strictPropertyInitialization`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-class-initialization) which will warn you that you did not initialize `adds`.

Comment: The overwhelming convention in TypeScript (inherited from JavaScript) is that interfaces start with a capital letter. So `Addition` rather than `addition`. You can obviously use anything you like in your own code, but when asking for help, using standard conventions makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: The code in `Calculator` seems odd. It declares properties it never uses (and doesn't need, from the apparent API it provides). What are the `adds`, `num1`, and `num2` properties for? You're accepting the numbers as parameters to `add` and `sub`, and `Calculator` itself is the `addition` object.

Answer (score 3):

You did not initialize the `adds` field in the declaration. So before using it the method `sub` you need to initialize it:

```
 this.adds = //initialize with a value before using it in the next line.
 this.adds.num1=12;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what the `adds` in `Calculator` is meant to be, but nothing in your code *creates* an `addition` object and assigns it to `adds`, so `adds` is `undefined`, and you can't access properties on `undefined`. Just declaring the property for it doesn't create it. You have to either create one or receive one. (But I suspect you don't want `adds` at all.)

---

FWIW:

The code in `Calculator` seems odd. It declares properties it never uses (and doesn't need, from the apparent API it provides). What are the `adds`, `num1`, and `num2` properties for? You're accepting the numbers as parameters to `add` and `sub`, and `Calculator` itself is the `addition` object.

Without those properties, it would be rather simpler:

```
interface Addition { 
    add(num1:number, num2:number): number;
}
class Calculator implements addition {
    add(num1: number, num2: number): number { 
        return num1 + num2;
    }    

    sub(num1: number, num2: number): number { 
        return num1 - num2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, what you're trying to achieve, but I think a proper design would be:

```
interface Addition {
    add(num1: number, num2: number): number;
}

interface Subtraction {
    sub(num1: number, num2: number): number;
}

class Calculator implements Addition, Subtraction {

    add(num1: number, num2: number): number {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    sub(num1: number, num2: number): number {
        return num1 - num2
    }
}

let cal = new Calculator();
console.log(cal.add(1, 2));
console.log(cal.sub(2, 3));
```

Comment: They could be looking to design some history functionality. The design would obviously need some additions.